# Count no of click on my own ads using AdMob?

Tags: android, admob

I have integrated AdMob in my application. And i want to show (custom) ads of Let's say company XYZ, but how to count clicks on these ads ?

Comment: Can't you just look at the admob dashboard?

Comment: I didn't try this, i just read documentation. And didn't find any thing related to my requirement...

Comment: As far as I know thats the only way to see. I don't think the SDK has an onclick method for you to use... that could be abused.

Answer (score 0):

You could [create a custom event](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/training/mediation/custom-events/banners) that returns an ad from company XYZ, and add this custom event to a mediation placement. Then use that mediation placement ID in your app when making ad requests, and they will get sent to your custom event.

When implementing your custom event, make sure to invoke `CustomEventBannerListener.onClick()` when the ad is clicked. This is how AdMob knows to record a click for your custom event, and you can track these clicks via AdMob mediation reporting.